# Top alignment of SetCell command

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tabularray, longtblr

Hi there I am trying align the "2403 Y" to the top of the 4 connected rows and not in the middle of the 4 connected rows.

```
\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Ergebnisse der Gitterschnittprüfung der bei $40^{\circ}C$ gehärteten Proben PUA 2403 X, -Y und -Z},
    label = {tblr:GT 40 grad},
    ]
{width=\linewidth,colspec={X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]}}
\hline
 \textbf{PUA Nr.} & \textbf{Substrat} & \textbf{Blech Nr.} & \textbf{GT Nr. 1} & \textbf{GT Nr. 2} & \textbf{GT Nr. 3} & \textbf{Mittelwert} & \textbf{Stabw. S}\\
\hline
\SetCell[r=4]{c} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2403 X}& Oxsilan & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\hline
&Fe Phosphatiert & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
&Zn Phosphatiert & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
&Gestrahltes Aluminium & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
\SetCell[r=4]{c} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2403 Y}& Oxsilan & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\hline
&Fe Phosphatiert & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
&Zn Phosphatiert & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
&Gestrahltes Aluminium & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
\SetCell[r=4]{c} \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{2403 Z}& Oxsilan & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\\hline
&Fe Phosphatiert & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
&Zn Phosphatiert & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
&Gestrahltes Aluminium & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{longtblr}
```

Ty for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, next time, give a MWE (starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`

The key is `cell{6}{1} = {r=4,c=1}{h,cmd=\rotatebox{90}},`

I made a few changes:

- `colspec={X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]|X[1,c]` by
  `colspec={*{8}{X[c]}},`
- `vline{1} = {1-Z}{0pt}` and `vline{9} = {1-Z}{0pt}` for special cases
- `Setcells` with the new `\cell` interface
- for non-centered alignment, replace with `f` or `h`
- EDIT: caption in bold

**The code**

```
\documentclass{article}
%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/690054/top-alignment-of-setcell-command
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\bfseries}%<<< edit

\begin{longtblr}[
    caption = {Ergebnisse der Gitterschnittprüfung der bei $40^{\circ}C$ gehärteten Proben PUA 2403 X, -Y und -Z},
    label = {tblr:GT 40 grad},
    ]
    {
        width=\linewidth,
        colspec={*{8}{X[c,m]}},
        hlines,vlines,
        % vline{1} = {1-Z}{0pt},
        % vline{9} = {1-Z}{0pt},
        vline{1,9} = {1-Z}{0pt},%<--  in one line
        row{1}={font=\bfseries},
        % cell{2}{1} = {r=4,c=1}{c,cmd=\rotatebox{90}},
        cell{6}{1} = {r=4,c=1}{h,cmd=\rotatebox{90}},
        % cell{10}{1} = {r=4,c=1}{c,cmd=\rotatebox{90}},
        cell{2,10}{1} = {r=4,c=1}{c,cmd=\rotatebox{90}},%<--  in one line
    }
%
PUA Nr. & Substrat & Blech Nr. & GT Nr. 1 & GT Nr. 2 & GT Nr. 3 & Mittelwert & Stabw. S\\
%
2403 X& Oxsilan & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\%
&Fe Phosphatiert & 5 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\%
&Zn Phosphatiert & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\%
&Gestrahltes Aluminium & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
%
2403 Y& Oxsilan & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\%
&Fe Phosphatiert & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\%
&Zn Phosphatiert & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\%
&Gestrahltes Aluminium & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
%
2403 Z& Oxsilan & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\%
&Fe Phosphatiert & 4 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\%
&Zn Phosphatiert & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\%
&Gestrahltes Aluminium & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
%
\end{longtblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very much. Next time ill create a MWE. Can i ask you maybe one more thing. how can the "Table 1: " be in bold?

Comment: With this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/258098/how-do-i-change-the-style-of-a-longtable-caption?

Comment: didnt work i tried both \captionsetup[longtblr]{labelfont=bf} and \captionsetup[longtable]{labelfont=bf}

Comment: with this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/669041/bold-caption-tag-in-tabularray-table,  I add it

Answer (score 0):

I would write your table on the following way:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\small\bfseries} 
\SetTblrStyle{caption-text}{font=\small}

\begin{document}
    \begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Ergebnisse der Gitterschnittprüfung der bei \qty{40}{\degreeCelsius} gehärteten Proben PUA 2403 X, -Y und -Z},
  label = {tblr:GT 40 grad},
                    ]{hlines, vlines, 
                      colspec = {X[0.5, c,m] X[1.2, c,m] *{6}{X[c,m]} },
                      colsep  = 3pt,
                      cell{2,10}{1} = {r=4}{cmd=\settowidth\rotheadsize{2403 X}\rothead},
                      cell{6}{1} = {r=4}{cmd=\settowidth\rotheadsize{2403 X}\rothead, h},
                      row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
                      }
PUA Nr. & Substrat  & Blech Nr. & GT Nr. 1  & GT Nr. 2  & GT Nr. 3  & Mittelwert    & Stabw. S  \\
2403 X  & Oxsilan   & 4         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             & 0         \\ 
        & Fe Phosphatiert   
                    & 5         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             & 0         \\ 
        & Zn Phosphatiert   
                    & 1         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             & 0         \\ 
        & Gestrahltes Aluminium 
                    & 1         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             & 0         \\
2403 Y  & Oxsilan   & 3         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             & 0         \\
        & Fe Phosphatiert 
                    & 4         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             & 0         \\
        & Zn Phosphatiert 
                    & 2         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             & 0         \\
        & Gestrahltes Aluminium 
                    & 1         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             & 0         \\
2403 Z  & Oxsilan   & 1         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             & 0         \\
        & Fe Phosphatiert 
                    & 4         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             & 0         \\
        & Zn Phosphatiert 
                    & 2         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             & 0         \\
        & Gestrahltes Aluminium 
                    & 1         & 0         & 0         & 0         & 0             & 0         \\
\end{talltblr}
\end{document}
```

Main differences to your code snippet are:

- for table is used `talltblr` table (since it is not evident that this table spans more pages)
- last six columns have equal width, the first and second column width fare narrower and wider respectively
- for rotate cell content are used `rotating` and `makecell` package

[image]

Unfortunately your page layout is unknown. In the case, that your table should be narrower, for example with width of default text block width of the `article` document class, that you should change MWE and `\talltblr` preamble to:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry} 

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\theadfont{}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{siunitx}
\SetTblrStyle{caption-tag}{font=\small\bfseries} 
\SetTblrStyle{caption-text}{font=\small}

\begin{document}
    \begin{talltblr}[
caption = {Ergebnisse der Gitterschnittprüfung der bei \qty{40}{\degreeCelsius} gehärteten Proben PUA 2403 X, -Y und -Z},
  label = {tblr:GT 40 grad},
                    ]{hlines, vlines, 
                      colspec = {X[0.7, c,m] X[1.7, c,m] *{6}{X[c,m, cmd=\hspace{0pt}]} },
                      colsep  = 3pt,
                      cell{2,10}{1} = {r=4}{cmd=\settowidth\rotheadsize{2403 X}\rothead},
                      cell{6}{1} = {r=4}{cmd=\settowidth\rotheadsize{2403 X}\rothead, h},
                      row{1} = {font=\small\bfseries},
                      }
```

and resulted table will be:

[image]

BTW, desired change of your table design make it (according to my opinion) ugly.